# Webpack: Exposing global variable without using ProvidePlugin and expose-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working in this ReactJS project and I have a requirement to read subfolder package.json, install them all into the node_modules and after, all dependencies installed add them to the global variable so they can be used anywhere in the code.

The problem being is that I don't have access to the jsons on expose-loader due to the syntax from webpack.config.js (I need to add them dynamically), so instead I created a loader that adding as test the package.json, gets the dependencies and tries to replicate expose-loader behaviour.

This is

```
var toCamelCase = function(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase()
    .replace( /[-_]+/g, ' ')
    .replace( /[^\w\s]/g, '')
    .replace( / (.)/g, function($1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); })
    .replace( / /g, '' );
}

var returning_string = function(dependencies_object){
    var final_string = "";
    Object.keys(dependencies_object).map(function(dependency){
        var location = require.resolve(dependency);
        var export_dependency = 'module.exports = global["'+toCamelCase(dependency)+'"] = require("-!'+ location+'");';
        final_string += export_dependency;
    })
    return final_string;
};

module.exports = function() {};
module.exports.pitch = function(e){
    if(this.cacheable) {this.cacheable();}
    var dependencies = require(e).dependencies;
    return returning_string(dependencies);
};
```

The problem is that for some reason even though the output is exactly the same, it is not adding the library to the global context while using the expose loader it does work. When doing both things I manually added the dependency to provide plugin which I'll need to replicate later somehow anyway.

Is there any better way to do this? Or I am doing right but I am missing something?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have this same problem. Did you end up using a different bundler?

Answer (score 0):

After a research I found out the [following](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration/) in webpack 2.x (I am using webpack 1.x but I guess the phylosophy is valid for my version) documentation about configuration says:

> write and execute function to generate a part of the configuration

So my approach to this problem is not to use a new plugin but reuse the ones that should work. Basically I wrote a new javascript file that creates all loaders that I need in a webpack.config way.

This is the file:

**dependencies_loader.js**
https://gist.github.com/abenitoc/b4bdc02d3c7cf287de2c92793d0a0b43

And this is aproximately the way I call it:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var dependency_loader = require('./webpack_plugins/dependencies_loader.js');


module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {/* Preloading */ },
    module: {preLoaders: [/*Preloading*/],
   loaders: [/* Call all the loaders */].concat(dependency_loader.getExposeString()),
    plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/package\.json$/, "./plugins/"),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(Object.assign({
        '$': 'jquery',
        'jQuery': 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }, dependency_loader.getPluginProvider())), // Wraps module with variable and injects wherever it's needed
    new ZipBundlePlugin() // Compile automatically zips
]
```

Notice that I concat the array of loaders adding the following loaders with getExposeString() that I need and reassign the object with the new global elements in pluginProvider with getPluginProvider.
Also because I use jsHint I exclude global names that's why the other method.

This only solves for node_modules dependencies, there is a different approach if you need a local library.